# SliceDensityPlot3D not found

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I am using *Mathematica* student edition, version 10.2.

When I use the command

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[  Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0},
{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,    2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

the `SliceDensityPlot3D` turns to blue, which means that it is not found. However, the [help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) says that it is found in *Mathematica* 10.2.

Does that mean that because of *Mathematica* student version it is not available or it might be downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: when that happens, do other system symbols (like `Clear`, etc.) turn blue as well?

Comment: Odd as it seems, I get the same result as the OP using MMA 10.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. `?SliceDensityPlot3D` just returns ``Global`SliceDensityPlot3D``

Comment: Although scrap that, after starting over it works fine...no problems for me (@rcollyer that was a typo, I do have 10.2!)

Comment: @rcollyer Clear and other system symbols are working.

Comment: @kaka I did not ask if they were working, I asked if they turned blue when `SliceDensityPlot3D` is executed. If they turned blue, it means it was a crash. If they're not, then something different is going on. If they don't, try executing `SliceDensityPlot3D` twice.

Comment: @rcollyer   Ok. Right now I am installing again. Will come back what happens next. thanks

Comment: @rcollyer Problem persists after fresh reinstall. Neither SliceContourPlot3D works and turns to blue. Clear does not turns blue. How to execute twice?

Comment: After it doesn't work the first time, run the cell again, without re-loading the kernel.

Comment: This time it remains black while writing but after execution time it turns to blue after execution.

Comment: try different slices, see if that helps.

Comment: no success. By the way I am on 32-bit processor and in my previous version I never felt any problem during execution.

Comment: ContourPlot3D[
 x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}] works fine. But all the symbols in gruop of SliceDensityPlot3D are not working.

Comment: So, do the other system symbols turn blue, too? If not what does `?SliceDensityPlot3D` give? The usual usage stuff, or ``Global`SliceDensityPlot3D``?

Comment: Only SliceDensityPlot3D and SliceContourPlot3D are turning blue after execution. After my fresh reinstall, they remain black before execution (that means that they are not absent from system) and turns to navy blue after execution is complete (instead of blue, as previously happening).

Comment: Both SliceDensityPlot3D and SliceContourPlot3D gives nothing. Not even the error message just they turn to navy blue after execution.

Comment: Well that's interesting ... ok. Write support@wolfram.com, and we'll do it that way.

Comment: I removed the version-10 tag because of meta discussions like [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/using-the-version-10-tag).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I believe this issue is specific to v10, though, but I'm not married to the idea of keeping the tag.

Comment: @rcollyer As mentioned in the discussion it may also be relevant in a future v11, so labelling v10 may be quickly obsolete. We also agreed that *confirmed bugs* in a certain version should be tagged "bugs" with the relevant versions mentioned in the questions header (see [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching)). The discussion so far doesn't seem to contain a community/WRI confirmation.

Comment: Finally ver 10.3 solved this issue. Thanks mathematica team.

Comment: @rcollyer I think the idea is to put the version of a tagged [tag:bugs] post in  the [standard bugs header](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1611/4999) and not use version tags for bugs.  (I guess this is in fact a bug?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 that came about shortly after I posted this. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Oops, I didn't pay attention to the timestamps.  Sorry!  :)  I guess I should've pinged belisarius.